# How do I hash in these 2 dataframes in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

so I have these 2 columns (`genome$V9` and `Impact4$INFO`) from 2 different dataframes as shown below.

Basically there is a value inside each `Impact4$INFO` row (structure would be like OE6AXXXXXXX where X is an `integer`) that I want to filter in each row inside `genome$V9`. I understand it is complicated since there are a lot of values inside both columns...

Thank you

[Column1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9v2B.png)

[Column2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3Qy.png)

Comment: do you want to merge both dataframes based on that id? or filter all IDs from INFO in genome?

Comment: Filter all IDs from INFO in genome$V9 column, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract numbers from strings quite easily, when the structure is consistent. Given your structure is consistent you can try:

```
library(stringr)
test <- c("ID=OE6A002689", "ID=OE6A044524", "ID=OE6A057168TI")
str_extract(test, "[0-9]{6}")
```

Output is:

```
[1] "002689" "044524" "057168"
```

Given you want to filter your genome data based on this, you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ids <- str_extract(Impact4$INFO, "[0-9]{6}")

genome %>% 
  mutate(ind = str_extract(V9, "[0-9]{6}")) %>% 
  filter(ind %in% ids)
```

Hope that helps? Otherwise you have to provide a reproducible example (post exapmle data here).

Comment: It is working just fine as you said, I really appreciate this post!